# What is the use of the Applet param tag?

Tags: java, swing, applet

Forgive me if this question is stupid, however what is the point of the param tag? 
I have watched videos and read tutorials and pretty much understand what it does, but don't understand the why? 
It seems the user can't use this param tag to input data, but the programmer sets the values (from what I've seen). So why is it used when we can simply do all that in the .java file? 
A practical example would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to recompile anything if the param changes. You can just edit html with text editor and voilà! Also reusability of code with different params on different pages.

Basically it's the same question as "why do we need *.properties file when you can hardcode all the properties as `public static String` fields in some class?".

Comment: I'm a beginner so I don't understand your reference to *.properties file. But from the answers I would assume it is just to reduce recompiling? It doesn't have anything to do with the user?

Comment: to reduce recompiling and allow code reuse. if you hard coded parameters in your applet code, then you'd have to maintain separate code version for each parameter value or switch back and forth between values. not a good idea.

Comment: basically you should almost always separate application logic from configuration.

Comment: Agh, I don't get it.. but we have no choice but to hardcode the parameter value. For example
`<param paramname="stuff" value="stuffval"/>` 
It is hardcoded?

Comment: it's hardcoded in the page, not in the applet. now you can have another page using exactly the same applet (with the same code, no recompiling, no additional files) and having `<param paramname="stuff" value="other_stuffval"/>`. also it's easier to modify html than java. no compilation needed, just text editor.

Comment: Ah, I see. I hope to find a practical use but I get the point. Thanks!

Comment: Another example is [this properties applet](http://pscode.org/prop/?prop=java.vendor.url%2Cjava.version%2Cjava.vm.specification.version%2Cjava.vm.version&format=TSV), which is configured by URL (that URL query string is translated into applet `params`) as to what properties to display, and how to format the data.

Answer (score 3):

A simple example might be a general-purpose menu applet. You don't want to have the menu existing in code, because you might want to change it or have different menus on different web pages. The menu to display can easily be defined in `param` tags.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can have a component that displays advertisements/captchas/whatever and requires a public key. The same component (without recompiling) can be embedded on several sites. The public key is passes as a parameter.
2. The applets' look-and-feel (background colour, font sizes, etc.) can be customized to better match overall web-page layout.
3. Marvelous flying unicorn animation can have customizable speed and unicorn colour.

Comment: The first 2 are neither here nor there, but it is worth it just for the flying unicorn animation.  :)